# Migrate from 2007 to 2010 without access to database

Tags: 2010, migration, backup, export, import

one of our customers has a sharepoint 2007 environment in a shared environment. Now they want us to move there sharepoint to 2010 on another server in another domain.

Because i'm not very experienced with this, i'm looking for a step by step proces.

I think i'll need to export first to a new database on a new (virtual) sharepoint 2007 server. After the import completed, copy the database from this new server to the final 2010 sharepoint server.

But any details, errors who may occur, tips, tricks, tools i should use or whatever may be helpful for this task are very welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the quick summary of upgrade:

1. Verify the hardware requirements first.
2. Try to back up the database from SharePoint 2007 using the SQL Server Management studio.
3. Move the backup file to SharePoint 2010 environment and restore the backup file in SQL Server in a New Database (say DB1_2010)
4. Before you attach the DB to web app, run the following powershell: Test-SPContentDatabase –Name DB1_2010 -WebApplication http://test:14212
5. You will get to know the errors, fix the errors first and then try to attach the DB using following stsadm command: STSADM –o addcontentdb –url http:// test:14212/ -databasename  -databaseserver
6. Problem will likely due to some customizations. But step 4 will help you eliminate the errors before you run a successful upgrade.

Here is the [very nice and easy tutorial](http://sharepointgeorge.com/2009/upgrading-content-database-sharepoint-2010-database-attach-method/) on how to migrate/upgrade from 2007 to 2010.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not came back yet. We had some issues other than sharepoint that had to be fixed first. Thanks for the tutorial, just what i was looking for!

Comment: I have also updated my response with executive summary.

Comment: I was thinking, The customer only needs his old documents and folders. Can i export these folders using sharepoint designer 2007 and import these using sharepoint designer 2010 in a new environment?

Comment: If you only want documents then you can migrate the documents using SharePoint designer but if you want to maintain the site structure as well as SP2010 functionality then DB upgrade approach is recommended.